# How can I make __dirname in a node module refer to the directory that the webpack bundle is generated in?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am learning Node.

I have a module which I use to read and write files to a directory which I am referencing in my module `dataInterface.js` as:

```
const dataInterface = {} as DataInterface;

dataInterface.baseDir = path.join(__dirname, '../.data/');
```

My directory and file structure is:

```
/app
  /.data
  /dist
  /src
    dataInterface.js
  index.js
```

I use `webpack` with entry point `index.js` (which imports `dataInterface.js`), and the bundle output location is `app/dist/index.js`.

My `webpack.config.js` is

```
module.exports = {
{
    entry: './index.ts',
    watch: true,
    target: 'node',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'index.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
        {
          test: /\.js?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|build)/,
          use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    node: {
      __dirname: true,
    },
  };
}
```

The part

```
    node: {
      __dirname: true,
    },
```

is important. When set to true, the reference to `__dirname` in `dataInterface.js` is `src`, so `path.join(__dirname, '../.data/');` does resolve to the `.data` directory in the root folder.

But what I want is for `__dirname` to refer to `dist`, which is where the bundle is located. In that case ultimately I want to put `.data` in `dist`.

Is this possible and what am I missing in conceptual terms here?

Comment: Could you give a try to define a global variable with the value of the __dirname?

Comment: @JasonAshley if the setting is false I get an absolute path.

Comment: @SiddharthYadav yes but I'm wondering if that is really the way people do it idiomatically.

Comment: Yes, you can share the global, only if its a trivial data i.e. not something that you want to secure like tokens or keys

Comment: After considering the approach of wanting to re-establish the __dirname outside of its default, I'm thinking you might re-consider your approach based on __dirname being specifically set to be used in the module wrapper see, https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper . Maybe keep things relative to your default setting of __dirname with `path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')`